# How to generate Random pair without repeating the same pair again in android

Tags: java, random

Is this possible or not?

Can anyone tell me how to generate a random pair when I call the app?

for example: i have 0-5 images and i have 10 buttons when i call the app the images are paired like this

```
        1-9=image0
        2-7=image3
        3-8=image2
        4-6=image4
        5-10=image1
```

If anyone known the answer please post the answer. it's very useful for game when you creating a gaming concept

Comment: I just want to pairing the images for two image buttons randomly:example i have one image apple means this apple image is set to two image button out of 10 image buttons

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use a (Array)List for example, and the Collections class to easily shuffle/randomize the list.

Example:

```
// Create a List with all your items
String [] names = {"Tim", "Jack", "Jake", "Phill", "Will"};
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));

// Create a Random object
Random rand = new Random();

// Shuffle/Randomize the list
Collections.shuffle(namesList, rand);
```

Inside the Collection.shuffle(list, random) method, you don't have to add the random parameter, but it gives you control over seeds, or anything like that. Of course you don't have to create the Random object if you won't use the random parameter in the Collection.shuffle() method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 This works even for duplicates. If you add the "cards" twice and shuffle them they will appears exact twice in the result.  BTW You don't need to create a Random object, just `Collection.shuffle(Arrays.asList(names));` will shuffle the original array.

Comment: About the random thing, I know but it makes it easier to control it with seeds for example. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: A good answer for someone with such a low rep.  I look forward to more of your answers. ;)

Comment: Thank you :). I program a lot 6 years already, and I'm just 15 years old haha. I don't visit StackOverflow too much, that causes my low rep. I think.

Comment: So you have plenty more years to add answers. I have programming in Java since you were 2, oh dear I am old, haha. ;)